# Intellisense not working with styled components extension installed

Tags: visual-studio-code, styled-components

I use this extension normally until today. The auto-complete function is not working. Here is my code.

LoginStyle.js

```
import styled from "styled-components"

export const Container = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
`

export const GridContainer = styled.div`
    display: grid;
`
```

My VS Code Version: 1.64.0
vscode-styled-components Version: v1.7.2

Here is screenshot
[image: Auto-complete Not Show Up]

I tried to find it in the GitHub issue but I cannot fix it.

Very thanks if you can help

Extension Version:
[image: Extension Version]

package.json:
[image: Package.json]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a known issue.](https://github.com/styled-components/vscode-styled-components/issues/354)

There is no official solution for now. A temporary solution is to install the VSCode v1.63 until we get a fix as stated in this [comment](https://github.com/styled-components/vscode-styled-components/issues/354#issuecomment-1030623405).

Had this issue myself today, the temporary solution worked.

Comment: I use Visual Studio Code Insider Program and it now working!

Answer (score 1):

If you still face this problem, you can install "visual-studio-components" extension in visual studio code extensions, this solved my problem.

Comment: I couldn't find this extension there

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS users, I just found out that my VSCode was no longer auto updating. (I did CMD + Drag VSCode out and in from my Applications folder) and updated it.

Once updated to the latest version, it started working again. Although a very weird fix, I'm sharing it here in case someone else encounters the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue so following are steps you can follow to solve this issue

**Step 1 :** Remove unnecessary Extensions from Vs code

**Step 2 :**  Uninstall the  the vscode-styled-components  Extention

**Step 3 :** Press Ctr + P and Paste this

**Step 4 :**  ext install vscode-styled-components

**Step 5 :** install the extension

for optimization you can Restart your Vs code

**and All set !!
^o^/**

2nd Solution :
You can insatll older versions or different version

**Thanks !!**